# How to retry loading video again once it fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page i am showing a Video loaded from Sprout this way

In case , if something went wrong , means video is not loaded due to **404 , or 403 http status** , how can i retry for 4 times ? (waiting for 5 seconds each time )

This is my code

```
<video id="video" width="200" height="200" controls>
   <source id='currentVID' src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>


var actualvideo = 'https://api-files.sproutvideo.com/file/7c9adbb51915e2cdf4/b6e4822661adad1aremovethis/240.mp4';
if (actualvideo !== '') {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');

    $('video source').last().on('error', function() {

    alert('something went wrong');

    });


    video.pause();
    var source = document.getElementById('currentVID');
    source.setAttribute('src', actualvideo);
    video.appendChild(source);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9974/

Comment: Can you clarify: you want the error to be handled only upon HTTP 404/403 errors? No other errors (HTTP status 0, decode/decryption error, network error, etc.)?

Comment: That does not make any sense. A 404 error means that the file/resource does not exist. Why do you want to retry loading from the same url that responded with a 404 error? If you're getting such errors and the files are there, then there is something wrong with your setup|configuration|code. Maybe you want to try a different source link each time?

Comment: @ChristosLytras While it's a pretty contrived example (and a bad setup), imagine that the user uploads a .mov file to Pawan's service to be converted into .mp4, and is given a link to the .mp4, but it will take a few minutes first for the .mov to be re-encoded and finally moved into that location first. That's the only plausible setup that comes to mind for this use case.

Comment: @JamieBirch absoltely correct , we upload a video to Sprout , it says video state is deployed but it is taking time to display actually .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
var retry = 0;
$('video source').on('error', function() {
    if(retry < 4){
      retry++;
      alert('something went wrong! Retrying.. '+retry+'');
      $n = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
        $n.appendTo( $('#video') );
      },5000);
    }
});
```

The code appends video's `source` again to the `video` tag up to 4 times with 5 sec delay.

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3uto3swj/

Comment: Note: this doesn't just fire on HTTP 404/403 errors; it will also fire (may be browser-dependent) if the video starts to load with a blank src.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple case of using `setTimeout()` to stall and try again.

```
// set counter before defining listener 
// we'll do 4 retries (or 5 total attempts)
let retries = 4;

source.addEventListener('error', function onErr(){
    // test for truthiness, then decrease by 1
    if (retries--) { 

    // after 5000ms re-append source
    setTimeout( function retry(){ 
        video.appendChild( source );
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

I tweaked your fiddle to put it in action. I removed the little sprinkle of jQuery, since you don't seem to really be using it anyway. Looks like you just didn't know how to listen for an event with vanilla JS. Plus I added a pretend network recovery and a cat. ;D

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9b6t2gub/)

Sorry if I missed any semicolons. I normally don't use them.

Comment: In my electron setup, you need to call `video.load()` to get the thing to play.  That probably has more to do with `autoplay` being off.